# Alt tag refuses to work in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, alt

My alt tags for images don't seem to work. I can add an alt tag in the admin for a particular image but I can't seem to display that.

My alt tag just remains empty.

Now I've been looking around for a solution and I've found the following:

```
get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)
```

but that doesn't seem to work at all, the alt tag just stays empty.

At the moment my code is the following:

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt=""/>
```

Any solutions for this?

I presume there is a standard wordpress function to do this, since we have the option to insert an alt tag in the admin area

Comment: the_title gets the title for page you are on, are you sure you want to display the page title?

Comment: Ehh no, I already removed that. I want to retrieve an image title and an alt tag, especially the alt tag. But how?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way: (not yet tested)

```
$alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$image_title = $attachment->post_title;
```

Which leads you to:

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" title="<?php echo $image_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>"/>
```

Comment: can you provide a Pastebin of the code for the whole page you're using?

Comment: I don't understand what that would add, I just want to get an alt ta in my image, this shouldn't be this complex since it's a basic wordpress function in the admin.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, I can't help as your question doesn't go much into detail on how your page is structured, and you said it yourself, it's a basic WP function but then again all you gave us was the code you were using. Maybe the issue isn't the code you are using, maybe it's HOW you're using it. And unfortunately, we don't know that.

Comment: Aha, alt tags only seem to work in the wysiwyg editor

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using Chrome Browser, it's chrome's issue.

or if not than try this one, it will definitely helps you.

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('image'); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="image"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code you post on your fiddle in the comments, I would say you need to change the way you have setup your ACF fields.

`get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true)` won't work because `$attachment_id` is empty.

It looks like you have set your ACF Fields up to return the image URL instead of the image object or the image ID. I would suggest changing the field to return the ID. Then you can modify your code like the following:

```
<div class="row bottom-margin-half">
    <?php $i=0 ?>
    <?php $teamMembers=count(get_sub_field( "persoon")); ?>
    <?php while (the_repeater_field( 'persoon')) { ?>
    <?php if ($i==0 || $i % 4===0 ) { ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="col col-lg-3 col-sm-4 teamdescription">
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_sub_field( 'image' ), 'full', false, array( 'class' => 'r5' ) ); ?>
            <p><b><?php the_sub_field('naam'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('linkedin'); ?></b>
            </p>
            <p>
                <?php the_sub_field( 'functie'); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php if ($i==0 || $i % 4===0 || $teamMembers===$i) { ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The `wp_get_attachment_image` function creates the image element and handles the alt tag for you.